# Changing div background image based on website URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three options on a site I am creating:

- Multi-channel
- Manufacturing
- Wholesale

When someone clicks on one of these divs, an onclick event will trigger which will take them to the relevant page: i.e. blog/multi-channel ...

However, all three pages use the same template.

By default, the three tabs are shown with an inactive `background` image (grey border, grey image), but on hover they will show coloured versions of them. [As shown here](https://www.sanderson.com/customers).

The issue I am having is since the default background image is set in the HTML

I want the coloured version of each background image to stay active depending on which URL the user is on.

**Use case**:

[User clicks on page](https://www.sanderson.com/customers) (shows all three categories) > User clicks "Manufacturing" to only show manufacturing posts > On "Manufacturing" click, [user is sent here](https://www.sanderson.com/customers/topic/manufacturing) > ... From here, since the user has filtered Manufacturing, I want the red Manufacturing BG to stay active.

The issue is all four pages (three categories and the hub page), they all use the same template. Therefore I'm unsure on how I can do "`if user on this category, background: url = this ...`".

Wondering if JavaScript can help with this?

**Snippet**:

Live example here: https://www.sanderson.com/customers

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.row.blogFilter .span4 {
  height: 168px;
}

.row.blogFilter .span4 .message {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*** HOVER PROPERTIES***/

.row.blogFilter .span4:nth-child(1):hover {
  background: url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/1-active.png')50% 50% no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #005aa0;
}

.row.blogFilter .span4:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/2-active.png')50% 50% no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover;
}

.row.blogFilter .span4:nth-child(3):hover {
  background: url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/3-active.png')50% 50% no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover;
}

.span4:hover .message .multi-channel {
  color: #005aa0;
}

.span4:hover .message .manufacturing {
  color: #b51c22;
}

.span4:hover .message .wholesale {
  color: #009ae4;
}
```

```html
<div class="row blogFilter">
<div id="multi-active" class="span4" onclick="window.location.href='/customers/topic/multi-channel-retail';" style="background: url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/1-inactive.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;">
<div class="message"><span id="multi-text" class="multi-channel filter-link-count">Multi-Channel Retail </span></div>
</div>
<div id="manufacturing-active" class="span4" onclick="window.location.href='/customers/topic/manufacturing';" style="background: url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/2-inactive.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;">
<div class="message"><span id="manufacturing-text" class="manufacturing">Manufacturing</span></div>
</div>
<div id="wholesale-active" class="span4" onclick="window.location.href='/customers/topic/wholesale-distribution';" style="background: url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/3-inactive.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;">
<div class="message"><span id="wholesale-text" class="wholesale">Wholesale Distribution</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

What I've tried:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.href === "/customers/topic/multi-channel-retail") {
        document.getElementById("multi-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/1-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("multi-text").style.color = "#005aa0";
    }
    else if(window.location.href === "customers/topic/manufacturing") {
        document.getElementById("manufacturing-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/2-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("manufacturing-text").style.color = "#b51c22";
    } 
    else if(window.location.href === "/customers/topic/wholesale-distribution") {
        document.getElementById("wholesale-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/3-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("wholesale-text").style.color = "#009ae4";
    } 
</script>
```

My thinking in the above was to check if what URL the user is on and then change the background image accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.href === "/customers/topic/multi-channel-retail") {
        document.getElementById("multi-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/1-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("multi-text").style.color = "#005aa0";
    }
    else if(window.location.href === "customers/topic/manufacturing") {
        document.getElementById("manufacturing-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/2-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("manufacturing-text").style.color = "#b51c22";
    } 
    else if(window.location.href === "/customers/topic/wholesale-distribution") {
        document.getElementById("wholesale-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/3-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("wholesale-text").style.color = "#009ae4";
    } 
</script>
```

with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.pathname === "/customers/topic/multi-channel-retail") {
        document.getElementById("multi-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/1-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("multi-text").style.color = "#005aa0";
    }
    else if(window.location.pathname === "/customers/topic/manufacturing") {
        document.getElementById("manufacturing-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/2-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("manufacturing-text").style.color = "#b51c22";
    } 
    else if(window.location.pathname === "/customers/topic/wholesale-distribution") {
        document.getElementById("wholesale-active").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/3-active.png')";
        document.getElementById("wholesale-text").style.color = "#009ae4";
    } 
</script>
```

this would do the trick, however I would suggest you, to modify your HTML and add a class on this line like "MANUFACTURING-CSS-CLASS-ACTIVE"

```
<div id="manufacturing-active" class="span4 MANUFACTURING-CSS-CLASS-ACTIVE" onclick="window.location.href='/customers/topic/manufacturing';" style="background: url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/2-inactive.png?t=1528443115464') 50% 50% no-repeat;">
<div class="message"><span id="manufacturing-text" class="manufacturing">Manufacturing</span></div>
</div>
```

and in your .css add

```
.MANUFACTURING-CSS-CLASS-ACTIVE { //change the name of the class
   backgroundImage: "url('https://www.sanderson.com/hubfs/Customers%20-%20Blog%20Page/2-active.png')";
   color:"#009ae4";
}
```

you can do this for all 3 menus

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've amended my JS and CSS classes based on your suggestions. It still for some reason doesn't work? Only the hover properties are performed

Comment: yes, in your console you have this error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at manufacturing:121

you deleted the  id="manufacturing-active" , id="wholesale-active" in your div's, try to write them down in your html and it should works :)

Comment: ah, I had defined it in the HTML, but I fixed the issue by wrapping the JS in `$(document).ready(function(){` - Everything works now - thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `window.location.href` with `window.location.pathname`

Comment: Hi SG, thanks for your answer. I've amended href to pathname, but still no luck...